# How can I suppress a CMD terminal window when running an external command in gVim?

Tags: gvim, vim-windows

Running a python script from gVim on Windows keeps popping up a terminal window (cmd), even when adding the silent parameter to the command: `execute 'silent !python script.py'`. Basically the script has no output, and I am calling it with a keymap to encrypt/decrypt some files. The terminal cmd popup is getting annoying. Can I get rid of it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using `system()` instead?

Comment: Hello, I freakin love u rn. Did that and it worked like a charm. Suppressed the output with: let empty = system(‘script’)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Answers should go in answers (as I alluded to with my earlier comment asking Heptite to move their comment). That includes self-answers! PS Stackexchange uses markdown, so using backticks would give you code-formatting in posts and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Recent Vims can make use of the internal terminal to run external scripts. To enable this option, simply use:

```
:set guioptions+=!
```

See also the documentation [:h 'go-!'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27go-%21%27)
I am not sure this works in your case, but it is worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

There exists more than one way to prevent the terminal window from popping up in Windows, but I find the easiest way is to just use `system()`. For example, if you don't care about the output of the script (as is the case here):

```
:call system('python script.py')
```

Note that you can get the return value by checking `v:shell_error` after the command has been run.